# React Native 0.57 + React Native Firebase Crashlytics - Reports not getting submitted in iOS

Tags: firebase, react-native-firebase

I have a clean RN 0.57 project and want to configure Firebase Crashlytics for iOS. I installed react-native-firebase 5.1.1 and configured Firebase Crashlytics according to https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/crashlytics/ios. I can create a test crash with `firebase.crashlytics().crash()` in one of the js files, the app stops as it should.

On next startup, I can see in the XCode console that Crashlytics collected the crash data and created the report like this:

```
2018-12-13 18:07:11.955187+0100 AppName[896:371053] [Crashlytics] Version 3.10.9 (131)
2018-12-13 18:07:13.394373+0100 AppName[896:371098] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id '....' for submission
```

But I don't get any additional feedback from the submission as I would have to. I assume it should log something like `Submitting report` or `Crashes uploaded successfully` or anything else.

And, of course, no crash data is shown in the Firebase Console (though I can see the default dashboard screen with the charts, which means in my understanding that Firebase detected the app itself).